# What's the Best UI to Configure a Database Connection String

Tags: data, connection

What is the best approach to allow users to configure database connections?  The connection could either be SQL or Oracle.  I'm building a WPF desktop application.  Ideally this is the type of setting that is configured once and then forgotten about.

Some ideas I've had-

1. Just have a config file and have the user edit the connection string in there.
2. Have a configuration/connection tab in my application and have the user enter a connection string.
3. Have a configuration/connection tab in my application and user enters user name, password, server, etc all in different fields and I build the connection string.
4. YOUR IDEA HERE :-)

Comment: Options 1 and 2 seem potentially error prone. I would suggest you have each data item entered separately as in option 3, and ideally allow the user to "Test the Connection" at that same point via a button, with feedback as to whether the connection was successful or not. I've always liked that instant gratification :)

Comment: Option 5: re-use (or re-engineer) existing connection dialogs (since you're talking about WPF, I presume it's Windows). Don't re-invent the wheel; Microsoft has done a lot of research on usability and whatever details there are needed.

Comment: The functionality reminds me about FileZilla FTP client and how it solved managing FTP-connections. It's a free download @ portableapps.com.

Comment: @DeerHunter thanks for the suggestion.  I found the Microsoft Data Connection Dialog that was released in 2010 that I might be able to use.  I was hoping to have a single Window instead of a dialog, but code reuse from Microsoft is probably best.
(msdn)  
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection  (nuget)  
http://nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/

Answer (score 1):

[image: Squirel SQL Client Add Alias Dialog]

Squirel Sql client does this exceptionally well, a drop down list with an array of possible "databases" each when chosen will put a sample connection url into the URL text field already formatted as that particular database's connection string, and not to forget to mention a button for testing that the connection works.